# Client that communicates with multiple servers concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, client-server, python-multithreading

I am trying to learn multithreading programming with Python and specifically I am trying to build a programm that 1 Client sends data to multiple servers and get some messages back. In the first version of my programm I want my client to communicate back and forth with each server that I have spawned with each thread, till I type 'bye'. Now I have 2 issues with my implementation that I don't understand how to deal with. The first one is that I don't want the connection with the server to close after I type 'bye'  (I want to add extra functionality after that) and the second one is that the servers doesn't get the messages that I type at the same type but I can communicate with the second server only if the first thread terminates (which as I said, I don't want to terminate). Any suggestions would be appreciated. Cheers!

**Client.py**

```
import sys 
import threading 
from _thread import * 
import socket

host_1 = '127.0.0.1'
port_1 = 6000
host_2 = '127.0.0.2'
port_2 = 7000

def connect_to_server(host, port):
    client_socket = socket.socket()  # instantiate
    client_socket.connect((host, port))  # connect to the server

    message = input(" -> ")  # take input

    while message.lower().strip() != 'bye':
        client_socket.send(message.encode())  # send message
        data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()  # receive response

        print('Received from server: ' + data)  # show in terminal

        message = input(" -> ")  # again take input


threads_dict = {}
th_1 = threading.Thread(target=connect_to_server, args=(host_1, port_1))
th_2 = threading.Thread(target=connect_to_server, args=(host_2, port_2))

th_1.start()
th_2.start()
th_1.join()
th_2.join()
```

**Server.py**

```
import socket
import sys 


def server_program():
    host = sys.argv[1] # '127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.2'
    port = int(sys.argv[2])  # 6000, 7000

    server_socket = socket.socket()  # get instance
    server_socket.bind((host, port))  # bind host address and port together
    # configure how many client the server can listen simultaneously
    server_socket.listen(2)
    conn, address = server_socket.accept()  # accept new connection
    print("Connection from: " + str(address))
    while True:
        # receive data stream. it won't accept data packet greater than 1024 bytes
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if not data:
            # if data is not received break
            break
        print("from connected user: " + str(data))
        data = input(' -> ')
        conn.send(data.encode())  # send data to the client

   


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_program()
```

Comment: Python closes the client socket when you reach the end of the function `connect_to_server`, since the variable `client_socket` goes out of scope and gets garbage collected.  If you want to keep the socket open you must prevent that.  A bigger problem here is that you have 2 threads that want to use the `input` function and only one console.  How can you keep track of what's going on?  If both threads are waiting for the user to type something, how do you know which client Python will send the characters to?

Comment: @PaulCornelius I partially solved my problem by deleting the join() command. Now I am able to send to the first server a message wait for a response, send to the second one and wait for a response and keep doing that until I type bye 2 times.